# Error while installing Windows 3.1

Tags: windows-3.1

I'm trying to install Windows 3.1 on an old machine with already formatted hard drive to FAT16 (*5 GB capacity*).

I'm booting MS-DOS from floppy drive than booting setup from the hard drive but on the setup screen there is an error saying you need at least 6MB to install Windows, but I have more than enough space on the hard drive. Any suggestions?

Comment: better to quote the message word for word, and give a screenshot too. And as an experiment try formatting it to something much less like 32MB hard drive. I think 32MB that would've been a normal size hard drive back then. And by the way, win3.1's hard drice requirements are "6.2 MB of hard drive space (14.5 MB recommended)".. So try with a 32MB partition.. if it works then try it on a bigger one.

Comment: That is simply not possible since the Fat16 maximum partition size is 4GB.

Comment: It's 4 GB and 1 GB unallocated.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure without the means to test it but I'd try a 2GB partition to see if that works.

Comment: Please let us know if 2GB works or not.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to use an OS that old? I'd recommend a newer one. Also, it would probably be a better idea to run that old of an OS in a VM inside of a newer OS. Anyway, even if the partition is 4 GB, the OS still may not recognize a disk of that size in total.

Comment: You might have to reduce your partition size to 1.9gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAT16 file system only supports up to 4GB, so Windows probably can't recognize the partition.

Also, [according to the original Windows 3.1 minimum specification](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/89333), the recommended disk space is 14.5MB<- yes megabytes. Maybe try with a 500MB partition and see if you're successful.

Comment: I did it with 320mb or so and it worked like a charm, i guess it's fine with anything under 1GB. Thanks all.

Comment: Yeah, I remember my first PC with Windows 95, I paid extra to get a second 1.2 GB HDD (so 2.4 in total). And that was already rather big.